# How to drop '%' character attached to strings values in a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x

The following code to replace 'Not Available' with 0 worked successfully.

```
for dataset in all_measures_4cols:
    for col in dataset:
        dataset[col] = dataset[col].replace('Not Available', 0)
```

But the following code to replace only the '%' symbol attached to strings, did not work.

```
for dataset in all_measures_4cols:
    for col in dataset:
        dataset[col] = dataset[col].replace('%','')
```

Comment: Which `%` symbols are you talking about? Please show an example of your data.

Comment: % might be a special character, try `%%` or `\\%`

Comment: Will try the above. DataFrame columns values are of string type (98.2%, 100.00%, etc...) I want them to be (98.2, 100.00 etc..).